# WebAudio support on Cordova for sequencing audio

Tags: cordova

Is it possible to do audio sequencing with Cordova ?

I tried running this app on a Nexus 7 :

http://chromium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/samples/audio/shiny-drum-machine.html

(chrome browser) and the sequencing is broken (irregular beat), am I correct to assume

that since cordova uses the same chrome browser, it will be also broken ?

The same question applies to the iOS deployment,since it uses UIWebView should

testing the page under Safari validate if audio sequencing should work at all in Cordova ?